# Using pointers to input in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, input, struct

I am trying to get some input from the user to a struct in this function:

```
void adding(){
    Item *x = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    printf("Enter an integer.");
    scanf("%d", (x->any));
    printf("Enter a string.");
    scanf("%s", (x->text));
    printf("Which set would you like to add the Item to A/B?");
    while((scanf("%c", inp)) != ("A"||"B")){
        printf("Set does not exist\n");
    }
        if(A == inp)
            add(A, *x);
        else
            add(B, *x);

}
```

The Item struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct anything{
    char text[MAXI];
    int any;
}Item;
```

The add function which is being called in the end is this one:

```
void add(Array *S,Item *x){
    bool rep = false;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<(S->size); i++){
        if(compStructs(x,S->arr+i))
            rep = true;
    }
    if(rep == false){
            Item *p2 = realloc(S->arr, (S->size+1)*sizeof(Item));
            *p2 = *x;
            (S->size)++;
    }
    else
        printf("The item is already in the set.");

}
```

Since a runtime error is occuring when the first scanf() is encountered, I think that I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm handling pointers.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Also think about how `scanf()` can modify its arguments. Furthermore, don't use `scanf()`, it's wrong and evil. Use `fgets()` or `fgetc()` for getting user input, and `strtol()`, `strtod()`, `strtok_r()`, `strchr()` and `strstr()` for parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Then, you should use the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). It gives the number of really read items.

And `while((scanf("%c", inp)) != ("A"||"B"))` is very wrong. I'm sure the compiler would have warned you!

Should be

```
char inp = 0;
while (((inp=0),scanf(" %c", inp) == 1) && inp !=  'A' && inp != 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

first scanf should give a runtime error.
scanf expects a location of a variable in which the value read from user would be put.

instead of `scanf("%d", (x->any));` you are supposed to write `scanf("%d", &(x->any));`

because when you allocate memory via malloc all the bytes would be assigned value = 0.

so basically by writing `scanf("%d", (x->any));` you are saying put value read from user to memory location 0. which is error.

there is one more error which i have found in your code is when you are calling add() function.

it expects `Item *` as a second argument. while when you are calling it by `add(A, *x);` and `add(B, *x);` you are passing `Item` and not `Item *`. bcz x itself is a `Item *` type variable. so you are supposed to call it like this `add(A, x);`.

Cheers:)